# Convert PoseWithCovariance to Transform

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to convert geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance to geometry_msgs/Transform and how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270962/convert-posewithcovariance-to-transform/) by [Ugnius Malukas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30576/ugnius-malukas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If covariance is not important:

```
geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovariance poseWithCovarianceMsg;
tf::Transform transform;
transform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(poseWithCovarianceMsg.pose.orientation.x,
                                     poseWithCovarianceMsg.pose.orientation.y,
                                     poseWithCovarianceMsg.pose.orientation.z,
                                     poseWithCovarianceMsg.pose.orientation.w));
transform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(poseWithCovarianceMsg.pose.position.x,
                                poseWithCovarianceMsg.pose.position.y,
                                poseWithCovarianceMsg.pose.position.z));

geometry_msgs::Transform transformMsg;
tf::transformTFToMsg(transform, transformMsg);
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugnius Malukas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30576/ugnius-malukas/) with karma: 18 on 2017-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0